# Combining registers in vim

Tags: vim, concatenation, vim-registers

Is it possible to combine registers in vim? For example, if I have registers "a, "b, "c, can I easily create register "d which is a concatenation of all three? That is, without pasting them all and then selecting the whole thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the command `:let @a = "something"` you can **assign** to a register.

With the command `:let @A = "another thing"` or `:let @a .= "another thing"` you can **append** to a register.

Lets say your registers are filled as follows (inspected using the *reg* command)

```
:reg a b c
--- Registers ---
"a Apple^J
"b Pear^J
"c Banana^J
```

Then you can call

```
:let @D = @a
:let @D = @b
:ley @D = @c
```

or

```
:let @d = @a . @b . @c
```

And your register d looks like

```
:reg d
--- Registers ---
"d Apple^JPear^JBanana
```

Comment: I find `:let @d .= @a` easier to remember/type than `:let @D = @a`, and also just doing that for each register that presumes `"d` is empty first (which of course can be ensured, using `:let @d = ""`).  Good explanation, though.

Comment: Indeed it seems easier. I actually wasn't aware of the `.=` notation.

Answer (score 3):

```
:let @d = @a . @b . @c
```